# Entitfy Framework DbContext and xxxEntities?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a SQL server db ( with tables etc) and ive installed ef6 in order to use async stuff ( p.s. im new to ef).

So I added this :

[image]

played with the wizard and created a valid `edmx` files.

[image]

My db name is  `DUMP` so it added `Dumpentities` suffix :'

so now i can do :

```
de = new DumpEntities1();
 var data=de.AgeGroups.ToList()
```

But why don't I Have `DbContext` ?  like I see in [many](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/11/entity-framework-6-alpha2-now-available.aspx) places ?

Is xxxEntityes is a replacement for DbContext ?

cause it seems i can do all actions with xxEntites ...

## edit

Ive searched "dbcontext" in my solution and apprently i do have it :

[image]

So what is going on here?

does using xxxEntiyies is the new way ?( and not doing `xxxContext = new xxxContext()`...even if I wanted - I dont have it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `DbContext` directly (that will not make sense) in Entity Framework. Instead you use your own custom context - class inherited from `DbContext` which holds sets specific to your application. When you use database first approach this custom entity class will be generated based on *edmx* file data, which in his turn will be generated based on database schema.

Regarding to naming... its not obvious but custom context which will be generated, will have same name as connection string name when you are creating *edmx* file:

[image]

Actually this will be default name for Entity Container of your conceptual entity model. If you will open *edmx* file in designer and take a look on its properties, you will see:

[image]

If you will change this name, context will be re-generated with name you have provided.

Comment: Like i said , I see everywhere (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/11/entity-framework-6-alpha2-now-available.aspx) examples with dbcontext

Comment: @RoyiNamir can you point where exactly `DbContext` used in that link? I can see class derived from `DbContext`

Comment: `LocationContext()...`  , the suffix  is not Entities and I dont see any reason from scott to change it

Comment: @RoyiNamir ah.. thats just naming. You are free to name your context `DumpContext` or `DumpEntities`

Comment: grrr. so the default suffix is what caused me to think something is obselete ......:-(

Comment: @RoyiNamir in the example you linked, Chrome only found `DbContext` once in reference too; `As with other Code First configuration, this code is placed in the OnModelCreating method which is overridden on your derived DbContext class`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I've added more info on context namings - where it goes from

Comment: @lazyberezovsky hello my friend. is this what im looking for ? http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/20/using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework.aspx... and if so which part should be in ASPX.CS / BLL / DAL ?